# Deleting a CSS attribute without JavaScript

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the Bootstrap CSS framework that has this:

```
.dropdown-menu {
  left: 0;
}
```

but I want this:

```
.dropdown-menu {
  right: 0;
}
```

i.e. I want to remove an attribute and replace it with another - I can't get it to work using cascading.  I.e. this does not work:

```
.dropdown-menu {
    left: 0;
    left: none;
    right: 0;
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Not without explicitly assigning a new value for the `left` property, all you're doing with `right` is adding a property, not removing the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get rid of the previous `left` value set it to `auto`. To ensure it really overrides the old one you might also need `!important` (depends on the specificity of the selectors used, and the order of the definitions - but adding it won't hurt)

```
.dropdown-menu {
    left: auto !important;
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: @CodeGroover: Thanks for fixing the typo, but let's not remove half of my answer while doing so next time...

Comment: There is no text, only was code. May be you did changes while i send you edited version.